# Why don't loading indicator show when user save image to library in Swift?

Tags: swift, loading

I want to build the feature which let user can save the image to their library. The problem is that it takes a long time to process, so i want to show the loading indicator to let user wait in moment. But the loading does not show. How can i fix my problem? Thank for your helping. My code is below:

```
@objc func saveImage(sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        showLoading(viewCtrl: self)
        let imageString = self.arrayPost[sender.tag].image
        if let url = URL(string: imageString),
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
            let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            showSuccess(viewCtrl: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save image on background thread and do the UI handling on main thread

```
showLoading(viewCtrl: self)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

        // save image code here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            hideLoading(viewCtrl: self)
            showSuccess(viewCtrl: self)
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe `let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)` blocked UI Thread for a while. Try put this task to background.